# A list That I use doesn't display in a page WPF

Tags: list, xaml, mvvm, combobox, binding

I have a list in a model, I use it in a view to add things or remove things in it from a viewmodel. Then, normally I can go to an other page and view the list in a combobox. But now it doesn't show in the ComboBox.

I don't know how to in a way "cast" my list in the combobox.Any help is apprciated !

[List Collection in my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JCrC.png) Here is my list<> in my model Bibliotheque.
[List COllection in my first viewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPFgT.png) and here it is in my viewmodel where I add and remove item. Which result in my view:[The binding of the list in a listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ClAR.png) And here is the problem[List Collection in my second viewmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw8So.png) In my other viewmodel for my other page I recreate the list to use it but then in my view in the combobox :[The comboBox that I try to bind my list to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufHlg.png). When I add thing in the other page and check if the comboBox changed nothing happen.

I really don't know where it goes wrong...

UPDATE

When I Used a OnpropertyChanged(nameof(Collection)); in one of my fonction in my viewModel ComptesEtudiants I could now see my list. So the problem must be that the list need a refreshing when I go to the page...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```cs
List<Livre>
```

You should use:

```cs
ObservableCollection<Livre>
```

The [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-8.0) notifies the UI when you add/remove items.